# I left the bootable flash-drive in

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb

So I managed to install Ubuntu on my computer, dual booting with windows and was working fine. But I switched back to windows to access steam after setting up Ubuntu, But I left the bootable flashdrive in which I wasn’t suppose to do and when I went back to Ubuntu I was hit with a devsda5: clean blocks screen. In order to fix this problem I tried clearing the ubuntu files on the flashdrive and reinstalling ubuntu on to the same drive. But it didn’t work because now I either get sent back to the Dev:sda5/ screen from before or a purple loading screen of ubuntu shows up but nothing happens after that. Is there anyway to fix this problem? I'm not really that good at tech and brand new to Linux and I'm a bit angry at myself for not pulling out the USB flashdrive which I believe to have caused this problem.

Comment: Okay. Can you clear this up a bit? On a scale from 0-10, how much tech do you know?

Comment: I'd give myself like a 3/10

Comment: Leaving flash drive while you switch between OS will not create this mess. May be your Ubuntu installation partition is corrupted. Recreate bootable flash drive of Ubuntu and reinstall Ubuntu on dual boot. Be noted that any files you have created in Ubuntu /home directory will be lost.

Comment: Give Ubuntu a little time when booting the first time, perhaps ten or fifteen minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The bootable flash drive is not related to any of this. You probably need to reinstall. The bootable flash drive simply installs ubuntu for you and cannot corrupt your computer in any way.
PS: Please use the correct format for title.